# How can I Pass a javascript variable value to PHP in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project where i am required to pass Javascript variable value to php, i am able to do it vice-versa but unable to accomplish, this one.
Is there any way to get this done in Drupal 7 ?

Comment: You can refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834132/how-to-pass-jquery-variable-to-drupal-ajax) that already clearly explained.

Comment: I looked into the link above, and figured out that whatever data you will pass in the URL will be displayed as output of the call back function.
Rather i would like to make it dynamic, a variable which recieves a value is passed to a php page . Any suggestions on how to make it dynamic??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the value during loading page. You can do it by appending the JS value as query variable in path (e.g. http://www.example.com/new/page?demo=true) for requesting the next page. In PHP, you can use API [`drupal_get_query_parameters`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_parameters/7.x) to read the data.

```php
// retrieve data from www.example.com?data=value
$query = drupal_get_query_parameters();
$value = $query['data'];
```

Comment: Can you please provide a small example using drupal_get_query_parameters ?

Comment: @PanshulKhurana Just updated. It is straightforward.

Comment: in my hook_menu the URL pattern that i have mentioned is as follows : 
$items['mypage?%']
is this the correct way to mention the URL ??

Comment: @PanshulKhurana You only need to define `$items['mypage']`. Thequery parameter is supported by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via a AJAX call. First you need to create a custom module, with a hook_menu() implementation. Then you can call that path via AJAX and process the value with PHP. Don't forget to filter the user input ;-)